# Remote JNDI lookup using IBM MQ doesn't work

Tags: java, jms, jndi, ibm-mq

I have installed the IBM MQ server v9 in machine A, in this MQ server, through MQ Explorer, I defined a queue manager and some queues. I want this queue manager and its queues to be looked up through JNDI from a client running on another machine B.

Therefore, through MQ Explorer, I tried to add an initial context in "JMS Administered Objects", for the JNDI namespace located, I don't want to use LDAP server or File system, I choose "Other" option (check following image) and provide `com.ibm.ejs.ns.jndi.CNInitialContextFactory`(I also tried `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory`), the provided url is defined as `iiop://<machine_A_IP>:2809`.

[image]

Here is the client code:

```
// Instantiate the initial context
Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://<machine_A_IP>:2809");
Context context = new InitialDirContext(environment);

// Lookup the connection factory
JmsConnectionFactory cf = (JmsConnectionFactory) context.lookup("testConnectionFactory");
```

"testConnectionFactory" is the connection factory which is defined in the JMS administered object.

When I run the code, I always get an error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "testConnectionFactory" not found in context
>   "serverlocal:CELLROOT/SERVERROOT". FAILURE

### **!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! UPDATE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

**After some investigations, I found out that com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory is really specific to Websphere application server. I tested directly in java Main class, probably that is why I always failed.**

**In my case, I really need to deploy the client to JBoss EAP 7, is there a provider I can use?**

I tried to find a sample in IBM community, but everything is related to file system or LDAP server.

Can anyone help me? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What JNDI are you using when you use Other? What are you expecting to answer your JNDI requests? The queue manager is not a JNDI Repository in case you are expecting it to answer?

Comment: Hi Morag, the factory class for JNDI Service provider I provided is com.ibm.ejs.ns.jndi.CNInitialContextFactory or com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory when creating the JMS administered objects. What I expect is the connection factory can be retrieved by using the context.lookup, and then use it to retrieve the queue from the queue manager. I succeeded by using the file system way.

Comment: I would expect either file or LDAP to work, but your question said you didn't want to use either of them, hence my comment. Without knowing what you want to happen, it's hard to provide you with an answer. You didn't say whether you expected the queue manager to be your JNDI lookup in the 'Other' case?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, I want the queue manager to be looked up through JNDI in the 'Other' case, is there a way to do it?

Comment: OK, well as noted in my earlier comment, the queue manager is not able to act as a JNDI repository. That is why you have to use either file or LDAP. If you edit your question to make your expectation clearer, then I can write an answer to say that to help future people looking for the same information.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to IBM MQ from JBoss EAP 7, use the "file system" option and create a .bindings file.  You can then copy that file over to your EAP servers.

You can then reference that .binding file from JBoss EAP:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <bindings>
            <external-context name="java:global/MQBindings" module="com.ibm.wmqclient75" class="javax.naming.InitialContext" cache="true">
                <environment>
                    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"/>
                    <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="file:///${jboss.server.data.dir}/bindings/"/>
                    <property name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="none"/>
                </environment>
            </external-context>
        </bindings>
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
```

Note that I map the IBM JNDI on to "java:global/MQBindings".  Something like "java:jboss/MQBindings" would also work.  The ".bindings" file is place in the "file:///${jboss.server.data.dir}/bindings/" directory.

This naming context uses the "com.ibm.wmqclient75" module.  The modules module.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.ibm.wmqclient75">
<resources>
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.headers.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mqjms.jar" />
<resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar" />

<resource-root path="connector.jar" />
<resource-root path="dhbcore.jar" />
<resource-root path="fscontext.jar"/>
<resource-root path="providerutil.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
   <!-- add the dependencies required by JMS Bridge code -->
   <module name="javax.api"/>
   <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
   <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
   <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
   <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming"/>
   <!-- we depend on org.hornetq module since we will send messages to     -->
   <!-- the HornetQ server embedded in the local AS7 instance          
   <module name="org.hornetq"/>  -->
</dependencies>
```

The jar files referenced can be found in the IBM MQ installation.